# Blazor webassembly: manage memory usage on client

Tags: memory-management, blazor, webassembly

We plan to make static some classes containing the data we get from the server so that when we move out and get back to the page we can show them immediately and offer to the user the possibility to hit a button to refresh them. So basically we are using static fields as cache.

As the app is quite big we are worried that this could cause memory problems on (less powerful) clients.

Is there a way to check how much memory the client has, and how much memory is used by that particular static field?

Comment: IMO, you should use the memory cache service instead of using static field : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @aguafrommars are you sure memory cache is available on Blazor WA? Tried it but the exception says "Operation is not supported on this platform"

Comment: Actually no, I'm not sure. An other way could be to use the browser session storage by js interopt